# Unable to click item in android app using Appium xpaths

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

My Android app is using a clickable GridView with embedded (unclickable) images.

The user is able to select an image and go through to the rest of the app because the underlying implemention has intercepted onClick() at the gridview level which conveniently passes through the ImageView element that was selected.

However, the app crashes when I click the ImageView using Appium/WebDriver.

How can I do this in Appium?

Thanks

Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out you can click the unclickable! The reason my app was crashing was because bad xpaths are not dealt with well by Appium.

I was able to get the View object and click it.

Comment: How did you do that. I am facing an issue for selecting image from GridView though i have id for each ImageView.

Comment: depends on your xpath. One thing I noticed was that the whole gridview needed to be visible (I used a swipe motion) otherwise you get IndexOutBounds error. Post your xpath.

Comment: Ok, please look at this post for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909548/ruby-selenium-unable-to-select-image-from-android-image-gallery