# Ruby Selenium unable to select image from android image gallery

Tags: android, ruby, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0, appium

I am trying to select an image from Android image galley grid view. This grid view has `ImageView` for every image. Every `ImageView` has id.

So when i am trying to get by `//ImageView[@id="someId"][1]` or by `//GridView[@id="someId"]//ImageView[@id="someId"][1]`, it does not find it.

How can I select image from gallery using `Selenium webdriver in ruby`.

**EDIT:**

```
<GridView id = "someId">
    <LinearView>
        <ImageView id = "someImageId"></ImageView>
    </LinearView>
    <LinearView>
        <ImageView id = "someImageId"></ImageView>
    </LinearView>
    <LinearView>
        <ImageView id = "someImageId"></ImageView>
    </LinearView>
    <LinearView>
        <ImageView id = "someImageId"></ImageView>
    </LinearView>
</GridView>
```

**EDIT**
As Uiautomator cannot select the thumbnails in Gallery, I tried to pick image using relative co ordinates but this is giving an error.

Is any one has done this? I need to select image from android gallery.

Comment: `driver.find_element(:id, "someId")` should work.

Comment: Yes I tried that too but not working. Also there are more than one imageview in container, so using this I can't get first ImageView

Comment: Need to see the HTML then..

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first image (`ImageView`) :

```
//*[@id='someId']/LinearView[1]/ImageView
```

Output :

```
<ImageView id="someImageId"/>
```

You can change the index in the `LienarView` array selection.

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id='someId']/LinearView[1]/ImageView")
p element
# <Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x3eb6a9d8 id="{ea847fbe-7fc7-453b-97ea-74fbf325ddac}">
```

edit : 
You can also fetch all elements using `find_elements()` into an array and then, juste select the one you want :

```
elements = driver.find_elements(:xpath, '//ImageView')
p elements[1]
# <Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x..f9bdc4412 id="{1f41fbd9-0a73-4fb2-9c98-44bb877e2388}">
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all this before. But can't get image from gallery container. May be this is an issue with getting image from gallery container for an Appium.

Comment: Weird, it's working on my browser with your XML file (webdriver). Are you using the `AndroidDriver` ?

Comment: Hmm, this is the problem with Appium, Appium cannot select the thumbnails in Gallery.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find it with Appium using:

```
//android.widget.ImageView[@id="someId"][1]
```

or

```
//android.widget.GridView[@id="someId"]//android.widget.ImageView[@id="someId"][1]
```

Comment: This does not work either. I resolved this issue by another way.